# jBoss UserPasswordLoginModule prevents from upgrading to Java 15

Tags: java, jboss

I have an application running under JDK11 and there is a requirement to upgrade to JDK15. I changed JAVA_HOME to the appropriate one and when I try to build I am getting errors on what seems to be a custom JBoss login module class named PlatformLoginModule that extends JBoss's UserPasswordLoginModule.

Extending UserPasswordLoginModule provides the overriden method `Group[] getRoleSets()`.

Group comes from a java.security.acl.Group package which seems to be removed from Java 14+.

standalone.xml contains this entry:

```
<security-domain name="customLoginModule"  cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="some.packages.PlatformLoginModule" flag="required" />
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I am not sure what that does but I assume that it needs to be preserved so I wanted to ask if there is a way to modify the login module or maybe extend some alternative newer implementation of UserPasswordLoginModule to get rid of the removed `Group` class and maintain the same functionality, or if there is any other way to go around and manage to run under Java 15.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java 15 is no longer supported and the Group has been deprecated for 4 years now.  Are you sure that Java 15 is supported by the version of JBoss that you're using?

Comment: @stdunbar I am using Java 11 and want to upgrade to 15

Comment: Is Java 15 - which is no longer supported by anyone - supported by the version of JBoss you have?  Not all versions of JBoss will work with all versions of Java.